# Google Search Console doesn't recognize BreadcrumbList and ProfilePage as strutured data

Tags: amp-html

Google Search Console is telling me that I should add structured data in some pages but Google Structured Data Testing Tool says that there aren't any errors (it found 2 itens: BreadcrumbList and ProfilePage).

It seems that Google doesn't recognize profilepage makup as a valid structured data or it expects to find some specific structured data.

Sample error message for [this page](http://advogadosnaweb.com.br/Advogado/Antonio-Caetano-7260?amp): Accelerated Mobile Pages > **Add AMP structured data, if supported** (Non-critical issue))

I know it is a non-critical issue but I'd really want to know what Google expects as strucured data. Should I just ignore this issue?

Comment: You may want to check this page one more time. I see that the <amp-analytics> is not closed. And I don't think this is gonna pass the AMP validator because the HREFs are not HTTPS. ProfilePage is supported: http://schema.org/ProfilePage. Error may be masked by other errors.

Comment: Thank you Jay. I really forgot to close the `amp-analytics` tag. The AMP validator has already validated my pages even though I've been using href with http. Could you point me some material about the HTTPS requirement? I think ProfilePage is supported by schema.org but Google doesn't recognize it as a featured or full suported schema.

Answer (score 1):

Your Breadcrumb is not a [Breadcrumb](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/breadcrumbs) it contains you Organisation.
See the [SDTT](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool?hl=de#url=http%3A%2F%2Fadvogadosnaweb.com.br%2FAdvogado%2FAntonio-Caetano-7260%3Famp) and Profil should be part of the Article/Publisher or as Organisation. Here is a [sample](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool?hl=de#url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.usa-reisetipps.net%2Fnew-york-city%2Ftaxi-new-york) of my AMP site with Breadcrumb and Article

For full support (like carusell) in the Serps you should add [Article](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/articles) to your AMP Site.
And your [Contacts](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/corporate-contacts), [Social Profil](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/social-profile-links) etc can you add on the regular startsite one time.

You AMP Site is still [valid](https://validator.ampproject.org/#url=http%3A%2F%2Fadvogadosnaweb.com.br%2FAdvogado%2FAntonio-Caetano-7260%3Famp) AMP and Snippet a two different things.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. IMHO the breadcrumb is correct and the organisation appears inside it just because I reference it by it's Id. I understood the difference between a valid AMP and Rich Snippet but I'm worried because Google says I should put structured data even though I've already set them in my page.

Comment: I think Google is asking you to add the "Article" Rich snippet to your site. This is a recommended feature to show a valid AMP in the Mobil SERP  carousell. Near article is recipes still suported in AMP SERP's